# Backbone structure for search form and results?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascriptmvc

I'm working with Backbone.js for the first time, and trying to get my head around how it works. I have a search form that pulls in results via Ajax and writes them out to the page dynamically.

I'm now trying to figure out how best to structure this in Backbone - [I read this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671435/simple-backbone-search-page-how-would-you-do-it), but I don't completely understand how to wire the form and the results together.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form id="flight-options"> <!-- options for user to choose-->
<input type="radio" name="journey" value="single">Single<br/><input type="radio" name="journey" value="return">Return
<input type="checkbox" name="airline" value="aa">AA<br><input type="checkbox" name="airline" value="united">United
</form>
<div id="results"> <!-- results, written by Ajax -->
<h3>Results</h3>
<ul id="results-list">
</div>
```

Here's how I'm thinking of structuring the Backbone code:

```
  var SearchModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    performSearch: function(str) {
      // fire the ajax request.  provide a bound
      // _searchComplete as the callback
    },
    _searchComplete: function(results) {
      this.set("searchResults", results);
    }
  });
  var SearchFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "form",
    id: "flight-options",
    events: {
      "click input": "getResults"
    },
    getResults: function() {
      // Get values of selected options, use them to construct Ajax query. 
      // Also toggle 'selected' CSS classes on selected inputs here?
      this.model.performSearch(options);
    }
  });
  var SearchResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    id: "results-list",
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on("change:searchResults", this.displayResults, this);
    },
    displayResults: function(model, results) {
      //append results to results-list here.   
      //update contents of blurb here?
    }
  });
  var searchModel = new SearchModel();
  var searchFormView = new SearchFormView({ model: searchModel });
  var searchResultsView = new SearchResultsView({ model: searchModel });
```

My questions:

1. Is this basically a sensible structure to use, with one view for the form and one for the results - the first view updating the model, the second view watching the model?
2. I also want to update the contents of the `<h3>` results header when there are new results - where is the most sensible place to do this, in the above code?
3. I want to toggle the `selected` class on an input when the user clicks on a form input - where is the logical place to do this, within the above code?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, that's a logical organization and a great way to use Backbone Views.
2. You could approach this a couple ways:

   - Have a separate View for the title (e.g. `SearchResultsTitleView`) that also listens for changes on the model. That seems a bit excessive to me.
   - Have your `SearchResultsView` update both the title `<h3>` and results `<ul>`. Instead of binding itself to the `#results-list` `<ul>`, it might bind to the `#results` `<div>` and have two functions, one for updating each child.
3. That would seem like the responsibility of the `SearchFormView`, either listening for changes on the model or simply updating the state when the event occurs.

Comment: Thank you very much - sorry this wasn't the most exciting question, but just needed some guidance!